# Calling C/C++ TCPIP Server from Java

Tags: java, c++, c, tcp

I am trying to send a TCP/IP message to a server written in C. The C server expects message to be in the following format;

//62 bytes

```
  struct SPMSifRegisterMsg
    {
        SPMSifHdr       hdr1;
        char            szLisence[20];
        char            szApplName[20];
        int         nRet;
    };
```

SPMSifHdr is a header struct represented as follows;

//18 bytes

```
typedef struct {
uint32 ui32Synch1;  /*  Message synch1 = 0x55555555 */
uint32 ui32Synch2;  /*  Message synch2 = 0xaaaaaaaa */
uint16 ui16Version; /*  Header format version = 1       */
uint32 ui32Cmd; /*  Command             */
uint32 ui32BodySize;    /*  Size of message body        */
} SPMSifHdr;
```

I am trying to send a TCP/IP message using Java as shown in the snippet below;

```
PMSBody pmsBody = new PMSBody();

PMSHeader pmsHeader = new PMSHeader();

pmsHeader.synch1 = 1431655765;
pmsHeader.synch2 = 11184810;
pmsHeader.version = 1;
pmsHeader.commandid = 1;
pmsHeader.bodySize = 62;

pmsBody.hdr = pmsHeader;

pmsBody.appName = "Name";
pmsBody.appLicense = "12345678";


Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3015);

ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());



out.writeObject(pmsBody);
out.flush();

 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


ois.close();
out.close();
socket.close();
```

PMSBody class is as below;

```
public class PMSBody implements Serializable{
    public PMSHeader hdr;

    public String appName;
    public  String appLicense;
    public int ret;


}
```

PMSHeader is as below;

```
public class PMSHeader implements Serializable {

    public int synch1;
    public int synch2;
    public short version = 1;
    public int commandid ;
     public int bodySize ;


    }
```

The server is a third party application and it should set the response in the nRet field however, i get no response. The API further states that i must add a NULL char at the end of all char variables (Is this possible in Java?). 
 I suspect that am not sending the payload correctly. How can i correctly construct the client payload using JAVA to conform to what the server expects. I have searched all over and don't seem to find a solution. Is my approach correct? Thanks In Advance.

EDIT

I have also tried to use ByteBuffer and still no success. My Code

```
        int synch1 = 0x55555555;
        int synch2 = 0xaaaaaaaa;
        short version = 1;
        int commandId = 1;
        int bodySize = 100;
        int ret = 0;
        String license = "12345678";
        String appName = "Name";

        ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(62);
        bbuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        bbuf.putInt(synch1);
        bbuf.putInt(synch2);
        bbuf.putShort(version);
        bbuf.putInt(commandId);
        bbuf.putInt(bodySize);
        bbuf.put( Arrays.copyOf(appName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), 20));

        bbuf.put(Arrays.copyOf(license.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), 20));

        bbuf.putInt(ret);
        byte[] bytesToSend = bbuf.array();

        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3015);

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();


        out.write(bytesToSend);
        out.flush();

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

        byte[] data = new byte[bytesToSend.length];
        in.read(data);
```

Am i missing something?
 Sample Java Code would greatly help or point me to the right direction...

Comment: *I suspect that am not sending the payload correctly.*  You suspect correctly.  A serialized Java object is not going to be anything like a raw C structure.  This question seems relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419322/general-socket-question-transferring-c-structs-from-java-to-c  Along with the endianness of each structure field, be careful about how that third-party application expects the data in the structure to be aligned.

Comment: The [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3419322/5221149) *(thanks to @AndrewHenle)* instructs you on what class to use for this (`ByteBuffer`) and things to look out for (endianness and datatype sizes). Try re-writing your code to do all that, then ask another question if you can't get *that* to work.

Comment: As for `String` values, convert to `byte[]` using [`getBytes(Charset charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-), e.g. using `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`, then resizing with [`Arrays.copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-byte:A-int-), making sure to truncate strings to max 19 characters first *(leaving room for the zero-terminator)*.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas thanks. I ve tried to use ByteBuffer still no response.. See ByteBuffer Code added above..

Comment: Did you read the first bullet of the answer to the duplicate link? If you did, you'd know that if you server is running on Intel CPU, you need to use Little Endian. --- `char szLisence[20]` means 20 bytes with zero-terminated text. How did you envision that `put(appName.getBytes()); putChar((char) (byte) 0);` would equal 20 bytes? `getBytes()` doesn't (likely) write 19 bytes, and `putChar()` will write a 2-byte UTF-16 character. Makes me wonder if you even read my previous comment. Hmmm...

Comment: @Andreas i have indeed read your comment lol... I have spent whole day trying to figure this out.. kinda frustrating as i am running out of time.

Comment: Your question starts out saying that message is 62 bytes, so why are you allocating 80 bytes? --- And why are you sending all 80 bytes? --- The two byte arrays are 20 bytes long, so why do you only copy them to a 19-byte array? Do you understand what a C++ zero-terminated string is? --- Why are you using `DataOutputStream` instead of just writing directly to the socket `OutputStream`?

Comment: Thanks Alot Andreas, Unfortunately little c++ knowledge. I've  amended accordingly. Have i set the byte buffer object correctly according to the struct implementation?

Comment: The 80 bytes was 18 bytes for SPMSifHdr and 62 bytes for SPMSifRegisterMsg